# Why is my For Loop exiting without looping?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a function to manipulate an array, by shifting the contents by n cells. The For Loop I am using (the first one) exits after i=1 on the first line of code inside the loop, and I can't figure out how to get it to progress.

```
Function ShiftVector(rng As Range, n As Integer)
Dim nr As Integer, i As Integer
Dim B() As Integer
nr = rng.Rows.Count
ReDim B(nr) As Integer
For i = 1 To nr - n
    B(i) = rng(i + n)
    i = i + 1
Next i
For i = (nr - n + 1) To nr
    B(i) = rng(i - nr + n)
    i = i + 1
Next i
ShiftVector = B
End Function
```

Once the code exits on the first line of the first loop (B(i)=rng(i+n)), there is simply an error message in the active cell.

Comment: You don't need the 'i = i + 1' in a For loop, it will iterate for you so maybe it's jumping ahead.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing the values of `nr` and `n`. Have you tried setting a breakpoint (F9) and inspecting the run-time values of these variables?

Comment: Try invoking the UDF from the immediate pane (Gtrl+G and type e.g. `?shiftVector([A1:A10], 12)`), so that Excel doesn't swallow the error.

Comment: `nr = rng.Rows.Count` will throw an overflow error if `rng.Rows.Count` is greater than 32,767. Declare `nr As Long` instead, and in general avoid `Integer` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend removing `i = i + 1` as it is not needed in a For Loop and changing your Integers to Longs to avoid overflow errors, but as long as `n` is less than `nr` this code worked to shift the starting position in the array. This is just an example with a subroutine, but I agree with @Mathieu Guindon check your values of `n` and `nr`

```
Option Base 1

Sub test_it()

    Dim rng As Range, n As Long
    Dim SVArr() As Long

    'values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
    Set rng = Range("A1:A10")
    n = 5

    'returns 6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5
    SVArr() = ShiftVector(rng, n)

End Sub

Function ShiftVector(rng As Range, n As Long)

    Dim nr As Long, i As Long
    Dim B() As Long

    nr = rng.Rows.Count
    ReDim B(nr) As Long

    For i = 1 To nr - n
        B(i) = rng(i + n)
    Next i

    For i = (nr - n + 1) To nr
        B(i) = rng(i - nr + n)
    Next i

    ShiftVector = B

End Function
```